# IPtables problem on CentOS 5.6

Tags: centos, iptables

I'm having an issue with IPtables on a CentOS 5.6 machine which was previously working fine, i'm not entirely sure when this began happening as i only noticed the problem when i came to allow a new IP on a port.

Basically, when i attempt to stop, start or restart i get the following:

```
Flushing firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle filter [FAILED]
Unloading iptables modules: [  OK  ]
```

For some reason, no matter what i do i can't reconfigure the rules. I've tried going so far as to uninstall IPtables completely (through yum), but even after a system restart it was still only allowing connections to the ports that were open before the problem began, and filtering everything else.

I'm really at my wits end, `iptables status` shows completely empty chains, but still no joy as far as external connections.

Any ideas would be appreciated. If you'd like me to provide any more information please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Sam.

EDIT: Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (it's basically empty due to having removed and reinstalled iptables).

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
```

EDIT 2:

If i run `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` i get:

```
Flushing firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle filter [FAILED]
Unloading iptables modules: [  OK  ]
```

And the empty rules:

```
$ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 81 packets, 6575 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 72 packets, 4133 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

But it still blocks and filters the ports.

Similarly, starting results in:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables start
Flushing firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle filter [FAILED]
Unloading iptables modules: [  OK  ]
Applying iptables firewall rules: [  OK  ]

iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  207 54155 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    4   228 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
    2   116 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:110 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:143 
    1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:993 
    2   128 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:995 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       -sanitized-          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/16       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22 
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 8 code 0 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  158 25662 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:!0x17/0x02 reject-with tcp-reset 
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   33  2351 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

But i still can't connect on SSH port 22 (i'm otherwise using a serial console).

Comment: Can you edit your question with the contents of your (appropriately sanitized) `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` file please.

Comment: No worries, done.

Comment: Could we also directly see the live ruleset, with `iptables -L -n -v`?

Comment: Added more info re live rulesets (stopped and started).

Answer (score 5):

This thread had a solution that worked for me:  http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=6981&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

The solution is to add the following lines to /etc/init.d/iptables

```
    echo -n $"${IPTABLES}: Setting chains to policy $policy: "
    ret=0
    for i in $tables; do
        echo -n "$i "
        case "$i" in
+           security)
+               $IPTABLES -t filter -P INPUT $policy \
+                   && $IPTABLES -t filter -P OUTPUT $policy \
+                   && $IPTABLES -t filter -P FORWARD $policy \
+                   || let ret+=1
+               ;;
            raw)
                $IPTABLES -t raw -P PREROUTING $policy \
                    && $IPTABLES -t raw -P OUTPUT $policy \
                    || let ret+=1
                ;;
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you running this on Linode (or other VPS)? I ask this because, searching for "Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle filter" in Google, I found the following reference:

**Linode.com Forum :: View topic - IPTables**
http://www.linode.com/forums/archive/o_t/t_3930/iptables.html

In that discussion, the relevant message is this one by user "*troublshootr*", that also mentions CentOS (I **bolded** what it seems to me the solution part of the reply):

> I asked the same question and it wasn't really answered. This is what I received from 
>   support:
>
> " The issue is that the "Latest 2.6 Paravirt" kernel has a "security" chain 
>   and iptables doesn't know how to handle it. **Usually switching to the
>    "Latest 2.6 Stable" kernel resolves the issue without any further tweaking** 
>   of the iptables init script (it often just ignores that chain and starts 
>   normally). Our builds team is indeed aware of this problem, however I do not 
>   have an ETA on if/when it will be resolved.
>   It is perfectly fine to continue using our "Latest 2.6 Stable" kernel -- this 
>   kernel was actually the default selection for CentOS deployments until recently. 
>   No applications, with the exception of iptables, will operate differently 
>   when using the stable kernel. "

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however unfortunately i'm not with Linode. :-( I also found that forum thread (searching for "Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: security raw nat mangle filter [FAILED]" really doesn't turn up many results :-P), and their suggestion of switching to an alternative kernel doesn't help in my case. This particular server is with 1&1 (who are awful, i won't be with them for much longer), but for the time being i'm really trying to get this machine working again.

Comment: if you do the flush manually, does all 3 give you the same result?

Comment: e.g  iptables -F INPUT

Comment: Flushing seems to have no effect at all. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance running Webmin or another control panel on this server?

I had the same problem with a CentOS 5.6 server where everything I did with `iptables` through the command line was flushed after a reboot; only the rules I entered through the interface in Webmin would stick.

Comment: The server does (unfortunately) run Plesk, however the old filter rules are being preserved through reboots, and even with iptables uninstalled. No new rules are being applied at all, despite numerous attempts.

Comment: Seems odd that the old rules would be preserved even with iptables uninstalled.  Plesk may be running its own copy of iptables.  I haven't used Plesk in a while, but I'm going to guess that when you say, "No new rules are being applied at all, despite numerous attempts" you have tried adding rules through Plesk?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't even get to Plesk - the port on which it runs was filtered for everything but our office IP. However, we recently changed ISPs so our IP has changed. We had added this to the configuration in Plesk (which does just create a script for IPtables) prior to the change, but hadn't noticed this issue and that the rules hadn't gone into effect until after the switchover.

Comment: Ah, of course! Trying to block an IP address recently for a client, I forgot their server had Parallels Panel. I'm used to doing things by the command line, was completely baffled when adding entries to iptables had no effect, until I saw your answer! Used Parallel's browser-based interface to block it, worked perfectly. Thanks, from the future :)

Answer (score 1):

In the error message, each of the items listed is a separate iptables table. Individual tables are supported by [kernel modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#iptables):

> - the `iptable_raw` module will, when loaded, register a hook that will be called before any other Netfilter hook. It provides a table called raw that can be used to filter packets before they reach more memory-demanding operations such as Connection Tracking.
> - the `iptable_mangle` module registers a hook and mangle table to run after Connection Tracking (but still before any other table), so that modifications can be made to the packet that may influence further rules such as NAT or filtering.
> - the `iptable_nat` module registers two hooks: DNAT-based transformations are applied before the filter hook, SNAT-based transformations are applied afterwards. The nat table that is made available to iptables is merely a “configuration database” for NAT mappings only, and not intended for filtering of any kind.
> - the `iptable_filter` module registers the filter table, used for general-purpose filtering (firewalling).

The `security` table is relatively new, and it's possible the kernel you're using does not have it compiled in. You can confirm this by running `iptables -t <table> -L`; i.e.:

```
adam@adamc: $ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

adam@adamc: $ sudo iptables -t mangle -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The real trick is, I have no idea how to tell CentOS to not bother to load the `security` table. Poking around in the init script may reveal a configuration file where those lines are listed; failing that, you can edit the init script directly to remove any tables you don't have installed.

Comment: Thanks for this response. I tried listing the tables as above, and it seems the kernel does have all of them (including security), however the init script didn't have a section for security. After a little digging, it seems that script pulls the table names from /proc/net/ip_table_names, so i edited the script to add a section for security, which actually "fixed" that (ie. no failure message on stop/start/restart), however unfortunately it still seems that the new rules aren't applied! I'm thinking it's an issue with the 1&1 kernel that came with the OS image... :-S